# How to save the current location of images?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I have a application that allows the user to tap and move a UITextField around the screen. Is there a way to save the current postion of the UITextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your header file, you want to make a CGPoint that stores the current location. You also want a method to save the current location of the UITextField:

```
CGPoint currentLocation;
-(void) saveCurrentPosition;
```

When you want to save the current position:

`[self saveCurrentPosition];`

saveCurrentPosition should look something like this:

```
- (void) saveCurrentPosition
{
    CGRect currentFrame = myTextField.frame;
    currentLocation = currentFrame.origin;
}
```

Comment: @TWcode Yes. Except you don't need a pointer, because CGPoint is a structure. Same with CGRect. You'd put it in the header file so that you can access the variable throughout the program, and not just in the saveCurrentPosition method.

Comment: Should I use in viewdidload ?

Comment: @TWcode Call saveCurrentPosition whenever you want to **save** the **current position** of the view. Maybe once in viewDidLoad, but probably also right before you move the view to follow the user's tap.

Comment: How do I call save currentPosition?

Comment: Here is the code that I'm using:                                      -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if ([[touch view] tag] == 101) {
        tex1.center = location;
        [[touch view] setCenter:location];

Comment: @TWcode Think about it. If you want to save location of UITextField before it moves, then call [self saveCurrentPosition] before you move the UITextField in touchesMoved. If you want to save the location after it moves, then call [self saveCurrentPosition] after you move the UITextField in touchesMoved. Try different things and see if they achieve the desired effect.